# Perl match overlapping sequences with a condition

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace a set of patterns with spaces before and after them using following regex

```
s/ $pattern / replacement /g
```

But it only converts first of the two patterns in a line (`$pattern $pattern => replacement $pattern`)

I tried `s/(? $pattern )/ replacement /g`

but this also doesn't work. Plus `$pattern` is composed of smaller patterns which I don't want to replace when the bigger pattern is already present.

Example:
Before substitution, string contains `ab ab`. After

```
s/ ab / alphabeta /
```

I get `alphabeta ab`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_ = " foo foo foo ";
s/ foo / bar /g;
say; # " bar foo bar "
```

The problem here is that when the first `foo` matches it consumes the spaces around it, so when the next match continues there is no leading space for it to match before the following `foo`.

To solve this you can use lookarounds so that you do not consume the spaces. For example:

```
s/(?<= )foo(?= )/bar/g;
say; # " bar bar bar "
```

Or in your case:

```
s/(?<= )$pattern(?= )/replacement/g
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the purpose of `(?<= )` ?

Comment: @user13107, `(?= )` is a lookahead, it matches only if the following matches the expression inside (a space in this case), but without advancing the position in the string and without including it in the match. `(?<= )` is a lookbehind, which works in the same way but for the previous characters instead. See [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

In the first replacement, the space between patterns is part of the matched string, so the next matching starts *after* the space. You can use a zero-width look-ahead assertion to make the position not advance over the space:

```
my $s = ' a a a a a ';
$s =~ s/ a(?= )/ X /g;
print $s;
```

Output:

```
 X  X  X  X  X
```